# Use REST to get a list of updated records only when specific fields are updated

Tags: rest-api, api

I'm trying to use the REST API [SObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) resource to give me a list of updated/deleted Accounts during a period of time, but I'm getting bogged down by irrelevant updates.

Ideally, I'd like to only bring in Accounts that had changes to specific fields during that period of time. Is that possible?

Example: I want a list of Account Ids for any Account that had its name changed during a period of time. When I use Get Updated, it gives me those Ids as well as every Account Id that had any other change that I don't care about (e.g. address change).

Comment: did you look at the AccountHistory object - that will track field changes (up to 20 fields)

Comment: @cropredy the problem is the fields I'm interested in aren't super consequential to the rest of the organization, so I don't want to waste track field change allotment on them.

Comment: I think you'll be best off using a trigger to write out 'interesting' changes to a custom log object